# override guava dependency version of spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

`spark` depends on an old version of `guava`.
i build my `spark` project with `sbt assembly`, excluding spark using `provided`, and including the latest version of `guava`.

However, when running `sbt-assembly`, the `guava` dependency is excluded also from the jar.

my build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "11.0"
)
```

if i remove the `% "provided"`, then both `spark` and `guava` is included.

so, how can i exclude `spark` and include `guava`?

Comment: Can you post the exact changes that you've made to solve this problem? I'm facing a similar problem where I have to shade jackson-core library but I'm having some confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for shading options. See [here](http://asyncified.io/2016/04/07/spark-uber-jars-and-shading-with-sbt-assembly/) but basically you need to add shading instructions. Something like this:

```
assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("com.google.guava.**" -> "my_conf.@1")
    .inLibrary("com.google.guava" % "config" % "11.0")
    .inProject
  )
```

There is also the corresponding maven-shade-plugin for those who prefer maven.